# How can a standard error icon be shown in on a C# windows forms dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to use the standard error icon ([Standard Icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511277.aspx)) on a Windows Forms dialog. How can the error icon be loaded into an Image for display?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By using Icon.ToBitmap()

```
Bitmap b = SystemIcons.Error.ToBitmap();
```

EDIT:

Three years later and one more upvote, I feel compelled to direct people who just want to draw the icon to a graphics object to read the answer by @Hans Passant.  It's a better solution.

Comment: As a side note, this requires .NET 3.5 or later.

Comment: @Evan: That's not true http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.icon_methods%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: That is easier than expected. Thanks.

Comment: And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemicons.error.aspx has been there since 1.0.

Comment: @Ed: True. Only the Shield icon requires 3.5 or later.

Comment: Ok, well, not sure how that is relevant the the example, but good to know anyway :D

Answer (score 13):

I have to sputter at the horrid waste of burning up such expensive resources as a Control and a Windows window, just to draw a dinky icon.  To save one line of code:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        e.Graphics.DrawIcon(SystemIcons.Error, 10, 10);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

Comment: Right, assuming of course you only need to draw it, not manipulate it or do anything else that you would need an Image for.  In that case, "sputter" away :D

Comment: @EdS - sputter, if you want special effects then you'd use Graphics.FromImage() and *still* use DrawIcon().  But I do admit at a lack of imagination.  Do you have a realistic usage?

Comment: Well, to call FromImage you need an... Image, not an Icon.  Saving it to disk is one.  Maintaining an image as a member variable is another.  Asigning it to an Image property of a control like a PictureBox is one more.  I admit that, far more often than not, you just need to draw the thing and in that case yours is a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Visual Studio's Designer, add a PictureBox object. Then in code, set your PictureBox's Image property:

```
dialog.PictureBox.Image = SystemIcons.Error.ToBitmap();
```